# Intel compiler not compatible with Libstdc++.so.6.0.30 version

Tags: c++, gcc, intel

I compiled my code by using intel compiler version is 10.1.022. The target machine is SLES15 and it has libstdc++.so.6.0.30 and my application is not working with libstdc++.so.6.0.30.

I copied libstdc++.so.6.0.28 version then The application is working.
which intel c++ compiler I can use ? which is compatible with libstdc++.so.6.0.30

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You probably have to use Intels own c++ runtime libraries.